# Remove ionic android platform

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to remove android platform from my ionic project using `'ionic platform remove android'` but it showing the error, `Platform "android" not recognised as a core cordova platform`. What i do?

Comment: what does the command `ionic info` give?

Comment: Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1 
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v7.6.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b

Comment: your cli version is old.. do you have an android folder in platform?

Comment: Yes i have an android folder in platform

Comment: can you update your cli and try the command from the answer?

Comment: Updated my CLI, and now its working. Thank you @SurajRao

Answer (score 13):

What version of ionic are you using?

if you're using the latest version,

try `ionic cordova platform remove android`

Comment: am using the ionic version 1.2

Comment: did you try "ionic cordova platform remove android" ?

Answer (score 4):

1. Add Android Platform

> ionic cordova platform add android

2. Remove Android Platform

> ionic cordova platform rm android

3. Add IOS Platform

> ionic cordova platform add ios

4. Remove IOS Platform

> ionic cordova platform rm ios

5. Clean Project Build

> cordova clean

Answer (score -1):

try `ionic cordova platform rm android` (latest version, v4)
or `cordova platform rm android`(v3)